# Usage of functool.partialmethod and functool.partial?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, partial

Consider the following code:

```
import functools
import inspect

class Foo:
    def foo_fn(self, hello, world):
        print(hello, world)

class FooWrapper:
    def __init__(self, foo_class):
        self._foo = foo_class()
        for key, value in inspect.getmembers(self._foo):
            if inspect.ismethod(value):
                bound_fn = functools.partial(self.foo_wrapper_fn, self, value)
                setattr(self._foo, key, bound_fn)

    def foo_wrapper_fn(self_wrapper, self_foo, bound_method, hello, world):
        bound_method(hello, world)

def make_foo(Foo):
    wrapper = FooWrapper(Foo)
    return wrapper._foo
a = make_foo(Foo)
a.foo_fn("hello", "world")
```

1. How does this ordering of the function `foo_wrapper_fn()` parameters like `(self_wrapper, self_foo, bound_method, hello, world)` come to be?
   and not like so: `self_wrapper, bound_fn, self_foo, hello, world`, since `self_wrapper` and `bound_fn` were partially bound first?
2. Is it ok for the return of `functool.partial` *(and not `functool.partialmethod`)* to be called by an object (`a.foo_fn`)?
3. If I replace it with `functools.partialmethod(self.foo_wrapper_fn, self, value)`  why does this error come up?

   ```
   TypeError: 'partialmethod' object is not callable
   ```

Comment: No he meant that - he is passing in Foo as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @DannyStaple: check, indeed.

Comment: @Danny Staple: passing the class is unrequired noise here. in the actual production code, i use a com wrapper and i can only instantiate later in another thread context where the com functions are supposed to run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both first arguments are *the same object*. `self.foo_wrapper_fn` is bound to the `FooWrapper` instance (as it was looked up on `self`), and then you tell the partial to pass in `self` *again*. So really, the signature is just a double confusion, and you can leave off the second argument and simply not pass in a second, explicit `self`.

Note that you are never passing in `self._foo` anywhere.

The order is simply set by:

1. The bound method, passing in the bound `FooWrapper()` instance.
2. Whatever positional arguments you passed into the `partial()` call, so 
   `self, value`. That's the `FooWrapper()` instance *again*, and the bound `Foo` method.
3. any additional arguments you pass in when calling the `partial()` object.

You *have* to use a `partial()` object here, not a `partialmethod()`, because you are setting attributes on an instance. A `partialmethod()` is intended to be used as a descriptor object, e.g. an attribute on the class.

This is why you get your `TypeError` too; the `partialmethod()` was never bound. If it was bound (it's [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) was called, passing in the instance to bind to), then a proper callable object would have been returned.

See the [Python *Descriptor Howto*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) on how descriptors work (bound methods are created via that protocol, and `partialmethod` objects, as well as `property`, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` objects, all build on the same principles).

So you could simplify your code with:

```
class FooWrapper:
    def __init__(self, foo_class):
        self._foo = foo_class()
        for key, value in inspect.getmembers(self._foo):
            if inspect.ismethod(value):
                bound_fn = functools.partial(self.foo_wrapper_fn, value)
                setattr(self._foo, key, bound_fn)

    def foo_wrapper_fn(self, bound_method, hello, world):
        bound_method(hello, world)
```

If you must have access to the original `Foo()` instance, use the `__self__` attribute on the `bound_method` variable.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! It looks like this is the only answer I found when bounding a method to an object (not to a class with partialmethod). And this is also different from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance), because here you add an existing method to an object! Thanks!